# MVC Asp.Net with Onion Architecture Not publishing Library Projects Dlls.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, onion-architecture

I have a Solution that contains a

1. UI Appliction -> contains UI &  References Core Proj
2. Core Project -> contains Domain Models and References Nothing
3. Infastructure -> Contains Unity Bootstrapper Proj and DAL Proj. 
   Bootstrapper -> contains Automapper and Unity DI config. and references (UI, Core, and DAL)
   DAL -> contains

Everything works builds and works locally but when I publish with Visual Studio, it doesn't bring the DLL's for Bootstrapper or DAL.  From my understanding it is because there is no reference between UI and DAL Or UI and  Bootstrapper. Thats because the DAL references Core and the Bootstrapper References Everything.   How do I get visual studio to include those in my published files?

Comment: Which design pattern are you following? How you build it locally?

Comment: Which project are you publishing?

Comment: I am publishing the UI/Web Project.  I am following the Onion Architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you UI project must necessarily contain a reference to the Infrastructure project, otherwise how would you be able to bootstrap Unity at Application_startup without triggering compiler errors?

My experience is that the entry point of the application always contains a reference to pretty much all projects because of such practical requirements. I would therefore suggest adding this reference to fix the deployment issue.

The important point of the onion architecture is to keep the core dependency-free like you have done, and to keep services (domain services and infrastructure services alike) independent from each other. All of this is achieved through a judicious use of Dependency Injection. The Onion Architecture is not some sort of religion preventing you from adding references in the entry point.

Comment: The output path ffor the bootstrap project ( unity stuff) is set for the bin of the UI project.  and I don't reference Infrastructure project from the UI becuase  the UI references Interfaces in the Core, which in turn use Repo Interfaces and the Concrete Implementation of the Repos is in the Infastructure.

Comment: Oh I see what you did. Then you would need to manually mark these files as "Content" in your UI project's csproj file so that Web Deploy knows that it should pick them up during deployment. However, I would really not recommend doing things that way, the best way to do it is to add the reference in the UI project, otherwise maintenance will be difficult over time. I use the Onion Architecture all the time and I have always done it that way. Having many references in your entry point (in your case the UI project) is not a problem for the Onion architecture.

Comment: The important point of this architecture is to keep the core dependency-free like you have done, and to keep services (domain services and infrastructure services alike) independent from each other. All of this is achieved through a judicious use of Dependency Injection. The Onion Architecture is not some sort of religion preventing you from adding references in the entry point.

Comment: If I ad a reference to the the Bootstrapper class it creates a  reference circular dependency

Comment: The problem is that the Bootstrapper class should not contain any reference to your UI project to do the Onion Architecture the right way, try to reorganize your project in that direction

Comment: Im starting to feel that. just need to figure out how to initialize the Unity from the UI project.

Comment: Take a look at this new problem that I've encountered. Any thoughts on how to get it working.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506031/mvc-asp-net-with-onion-architecture-not-publishing-library-projects-dlls  Its related to this Solution Structure.